# How to save a model, load and predict with the saved model on Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm new to python and neural networks with Tensorflow, so I have no idea how to restore a saved model and make predictions. I have collected data from three cameras (X_test) of a line follower robot and It's wheels speed (left and right) set by simulator for each camera view (y_test). I need to train a neural network to predict the wheels speed based on cameras views. That's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_train = np.zeros((2392,3072))
y_train = np.zeros((2392,2))
x_test = np.zeros((2392,3072))
y_test = np.zeros((2392,2))

X_1_train = np.loadtxt('X_Treinamento_3.txt')
X_2_train = np.loadtxt('X_Treinamento_4.txt')
y_1_train = np.loadtxt('Vl_Vr_Treinamento_3.txt')
y_2_train = np.loadtxt('Vl_Vr_Treinamento_4.txt')

X_1_test = np.loadtxt('X_Teste_3.txt')
X_2_test = np.loadtxt('X_Teste_4.txt')
y_1_test = np.loadtxt('Vl_Vr_Teste_3.txt')
y_2_test = np.loadtxt('Vl_Vr_Teste_4.txt')

x_train = np.concatenate((X_1_train[4:1200,:],X_2_train[4:1200,:]))/255
x_test = np.concatenate((X_1_test[4:1200,:],X_2_test[4:1200,:]))/255
y_train = np.concatenate((y_1_train[4:1200,:],y_2_train[4:1200,:]))
y_test = np.concatenate((y_1_test[4:1200,:],y_2_test[4:1200,:]))

n_inputs = 32*32*3 #3 images 32x32 pixels
n_hidden_1 = 300 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 100 # 2nd layer number of neurons
n_outputs = 2

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float",[None,n_inputs])
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float",[None,n_outputs])

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_1],stddev=0.1)),#4 inputs 10  nodes in h1 layer
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2],stddev=0.1)),# 10 nodes in h2 layer
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2, n_outputs],stddev=0.1))# 1 ouput label
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_outputs]))
}

def neural_net(x):
    #hidden layer 1
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(layer_1)#activation
    #hideen layer 2
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.tanh(layer_2)#activation
    # output layer
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return (out_layer)

Y_hat=neural_net(X)
loss_op=tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y,Y_hat)#loss function
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)  # define optimizer # play around with learning rate
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)  # minimize losss

init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
epoch=2000

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    for i in range(0,epoch):
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={X:x_train,Y:y_train})
        loss=sess.run(loss_op,feed_dict={X:x_train,Y:y_train})
        if(i%100==0):
            print("epoch no "+str(i),(loss))
        pred=sess.run(Y_hat,feed_dict={X:x_test})
        saver.save(sess, "output")
```

So, I need your help to check if I'm saving the model correctly, if not, how to save it and after how to load and predict with the saved model.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving it correctly, but if you want save more checkpoints ( for example: maybe last checkpoint is overfitting and previous checkpoint will give better results with test data), than you need add global_step ( your checkpoints will be saved something like output-0, output-2000 and so on), for more info look here [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver)

```
saver.save(sess, "output", global_step = i)
```

Loading and making prediction in your case will look something like this:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, "output")
    pred=sess.run(Y_hat,feed_dict={X:x_test})
```

"output" is path to your saved checkpoint